# Istio cannot access external services of MySQL，what should I do？

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I built a spring boot project and deployed it with `Kubernetes Deployment`，and its configuration file is as follows：

```
server:
  port: 80
spring:
  application:
    name: demo-kube-svca
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysql.dev.svc.cluster.local/kube
    username: root
    password: 123456
```

My mysql database is simple to deploy with docker:

```
Docker run -d \
-p 3306:3306 \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 \
--name=mysql \
--privileged=true \
Mysql: 8.0
```

Finally, I want to import the MySQL service into Service Mesh with `ServiceEntry`.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
Kind: ServiceEntry
Metadata:
   Name: mysql-external
Spec:
   Hosts:
     - mysql.dev.svc.cluster.local
   Addresses:
     - 192.168.0.123/32
   Ports:
     - number: 3306
       Name: mysql
       Protocol: tcp
   Location: MESH_EXTERNAL
```

However, when I use the program to access the database, the error is reported in the log:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql.dev.svc.cluster.local: Name does not resolve
```

I refer to the official documentation: https://istio.io/blog/2018/egress-tcp/,
I think it may be a problem with my configuration, but I don't know what to do, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServiceEntry` only open firewall in sidecar proxy for you - still you need mysql deployed on Kubernetes to use mysql.dev.svc.cluster.local svc or if you have mysql deployed under IP 192.168.0.123 please use it instead of host.

Edit:

If you need to cover 192.168.0.123 IP address with a service inside Kubernetes you should use [external service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) - as I wrote Istio's ServiceEntry only configure firewall.

Comment: My mysql has been deployed on the host (IP: 192.168.0.123) and can be accessed via `url:jdbc:mysql:// 192.168.0.123 / kube`, but using `url:jdbc:mysql://mysql.dev. Svc.cluster.local / kube` will report parsing exceptions. Is there a problem with my `ServiceEntry` configuration?

Comment: I probably understand what you mean, let me think about it, thank you.

Comment: I am using ExtarnalName to configure mysql service ..but still my application is not able to communicate with mysql. any idea